# 401 JWT Token not found - Symfony 6 / SonataBundle 5 / Api Platform / LexikJwtAuthenticationBundle

Tags: api-platform.com, symfony-sonata, symfony6, sonata-user-bundle, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm working on a Symfony 6.2 project for an admin panel (for a mobile app). The project has those bundles :

- Sonata Admin 4.24
- Sonata User 5.9
- API Platform 3.1
- Lexik JWT Authentication 2.19

I have configured and installed the Sonata's bundles and it works well. I have added the API Platform, and it works well too.
But since I need to do some critical action via the API endpoint, I added JWT Auth. And this, it's not working at all.

I have this configuration for my firewalls in security.yaml :

```yaml
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        admin:
            lazy: true
            pattern: /admin(.*)
            provider: sonata_user_bundle
            context: user
            form_login:
                login_path: sonata_user_admin_security_login
                check_path: sonata_user_admin_security_check
                default_target_path: sonata_admin_dashboard
            logout:
                path: sonata_user_admin_security_logout
                target: sonata_user_admin_security_login
            remember_me:
                secret: "%env(APP_SECRET)%"
                lifetime: 2629746
                path: /admin
        api:
            jwt: ~
            pattern: ^/api
            provider: sonata_user_bundle
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/app_users/auth
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

And this into routes.yaml :

```yaml
authentication_token:
    path: /api/app_users/auth
    methods: ['POST']
```

I can get a token via the `/api/app_users/auth` endpoint, like this :
[image]
But when I try to access other endpoints, I get this : `{"code":401,"message":"JWT Token not found"}`
In Postman, I have added the token bearer, I try my tokens through jwt.io and they are signed.
I try with this cUrl command :

```
curl -v -X GET "http://localhost:8080/api/app_users" -H "Accept: application/ld+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2ODYzMTE2MTEsImV4cCI6MTY4NzMxMTYxMCwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiIsIlJPTEVfU1VQRVJfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0QGFkbWluLmNvbSJ9.Q0OBJSq4gxwR1Ud_sGFA4smZro_8kn6NguicOBjGPeJ3OwOQKblSkxUYnqVsPOAOGy0Up50umk0b-tYc2bxzBhyDkZiKalT1kvyAvOlyd_BXLFsYk4uyNhehyni4pwBG_-JKA2NSumRCVSnV1vg8AVDmMUUalksjuKfR9Lsqfu8D6PIBvFm_eLR4m9WrvDQbE7gC6dQJaJE6UR2syvhSO-2PZX1EmpP2Y3QHe05pq27YtEeQ9Dflr6rI0E0DuFWsuA2qhwPAtZZtlCgIr-aL2S5raMbdnbesg3d61GVf3Gz0IHBAqyUnK7tJW_z8o_w-uTLX5LpICoGQ-Ctp417kWA}" -H  "Content-Type: application/ld+json"
```

But I get this response :

```bash
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/app_users HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
> Accept: application/ld+json
> Authorization: Bearer {eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2ODYzMTE2MTEsImV4cCI6MTY4NzMxMTYxMCwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiIsIlJPTEVfU1VQRVJfQURNSU4iLCJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0QGFkbWluLmNvbSJ9.Q0OBJSq4gxwR1Ud_sGFA4smZro_8kn6NguicOBjGPeJ3OwOQKblSkxUYnqVsPOAOGy0Up50umk0b-tYc2bxzBhyDkZiKalT1kvyAvOlyd_BXLFsYk4uyNhehyni4pwBG_-JKA2NSumRCVSnV1vg8AVDmMUUalksjuKfR9Lsqfu8D6PIBvFm_eLR4m9WrvDQbE7gC6dQJaJE6UR2syvhSO-2PZX1EmpP2Y3QHe05pq27YtEeQ9Dflr6rI0E0DuFWsuA2qhwPAtZZtlCgIr-aL2S5raMbdnbesg3d61GVf3Gz0IHBAqyUnK7tJW_z8o_w-uTLX5LpICoGQ-Ctp417kWA}
> Content-Type: application/ld+json
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Fri, 09 Jun 2023 12:04:54 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.56 (Debian)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/8.2.6
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Link: <http://localhost:8080/api/docs.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation"
< X-Debug-Token: 05c5c0
< X-Debug-Token-Link: http://localhost:8080/_profiler/05c5c0
< X-Robots-Tag: noindex
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"code":401,"message":"JWT Token not found"}%
```

I tried multiple things, like changing some configurations into the `security.yaml` and I found nothing which helped me in SO but nothing is working right now.

It's my first time with JWT so I have to admit I don't know where to start...

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. I found the solution here :
https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/index.html#important-note-for-apache-users

After adding this rule, the token is retrieved.